# Run Text to Columns on filtered data

Tags: excel, vba

I have data that is being put into a spreadsheet that has multiple lines with different starting text that I need to parse.  I figured I could put code in to filter based on the first word, then run text to columns on just the visible cells and then work with that data to get the cells lined up the way I want.

I have been trying to use variations of the following code:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

'1. Apply Filter
ws.Range("A:A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Inquiry*"


'2. Text to Columns
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ws.Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).TextToColumns _
  DataType:=xlDelimited, _
  TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
  ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, _
  Space:=True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True


'3. Clear Filter
On Error Resume Next
ws.ShowAllData
On Error GoTo 0

          
End Sub
```

I expected it to run the filter, show only the lines starting with "Inquiry", which it does, and then run Text to Columns with a space delimiter on just those visible lines.

I have used very similar code to find lines starting with certain text and then deleting those rows, which works fine, but this code throws a 1004 error as soon as I get to the .TextToColumns line.

Comment: `Text to Columns` can NOT be done on multiple range selection.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.  I will try a different route then.

Answer (score 0):

`Text to Columns` can NOT be done on multiple range selection. You will get the blow error if users try it on Excel GUI .

[image]

Please try

```
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    Set rng = ws.Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    For Each c In rng.Areas
        c.TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
            ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Space:=True
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```